# Asp.net 5 - VNext ViewData property in ViewResult is Null

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Asp.net 5 for a small application and i'm having a little trouble with returning a ViewResult from an orchestrator.

Where in previous versions of MVC we've done this:

```
 return new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "Index",
            ViewData = {Model = _formViewModelBuilder.BuildModel()}
        };
```

In MVC 6 this throws a null reference exception. Setting the model property of the ViewData is invalid as the value of ViewData is null? I believe this has something to do with dependency injection but i can't find a concrete explanation anywhere as to why this behavior is happening.

The simplest way i can get this to work is something like:

```
return new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "Index",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<FormViewModel>(ViewData, model)
            };
```

This uses the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller.ViewData property. I can pass this property through to the orchestrator but i'm not sure if this is just plain wrong and i'm missing a trick here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to get an answer over at github. The viewdata object can't be created without an IModelMetadataProvider or an already existing ViewData Object.

I solved this issue by passing the ViewData object that is a default property on the controller through to the orchestrator and creating a new object based on that.

Full details can be found here:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2814